# Getting all tables to DataTable[]

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I have an Access DB with multiple tables. I need to transfer them all to a `DataTable` array.

This is what I have:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    tables = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
}
```

`tables` is: `public DataTable tables = null;`

Comment: how about you  Call select statement on all the table's

Comment: Are you saying that the value of `tables` after calling `GetOleDbSchemaTable` is `null`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `OleDbDataAdapter` and `DataSet`:

```
    public DataSet tables = new DataSet();
    public OleDbDataAdapter adapter;

    public BusLogic()
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();

            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM City", conn);
            adapter.Fill(tables, "Cities");
        }
    }
```